# "Chi Chi, my dog, is happy." and "My dog Chi Chi is happy."

Tags: difference, appositives

What's the difference between:

1) Chi Chi, my dog, is happy.

2) My dog Chi Chi is happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've assumed that you accidentally omitted the comma after "dog", so I've popped it in for you.

> [1] *Chi Chi, my dog, is happy.*
>
> [2] *My dog Chi Chi is happy.*

The difference is that [1] is a supplementary appositive construction, while [2] is an integrated one.

In 1) "my dog" is marked as supplementary by the presence of the commas. Supplements are semantically non-restrictive; they add additional non-identifying information about the head noun -- in this case Chi Chi, the head noun, is assumed to be identifiable independently of the information in the appositive phrase. Supplementary appositives are not modifiers; instead they have a semantic 'anchor' that they are related to -- here the anchor is "Chi Chi".

In 2 "Chi Chi" is an integrated (restrictive) appositive. It implies that you have more than one dog, and hence serves semantically to identify which one of your dogs you are referring to. In this case the property of being happy applies solely to the one called "Chi Chi". Integrated appositives are modifiers -- in this case "Chi Chi" is modifying "dog".